# Defining routes outside app.js

Tags: angularjs

I have been told that in AngularJS, you are supposed to do all your routing in one file. Now, I feel like there's a fundamental problem with that. If you have a large web application, it doesn't seem to make sense to send every single route possible to the user. This would mean, that your main JavaScript file could end up with routes that look like `path/:to/a/part/:of/my/application`.

I'm used to a different way of routing, the main router has certain routes (e.g. `/admin`, `/blog`, `/about`). All the logic, such as further routing, for the blog is handled in (e.g.) `blog.js`. Within `blog.js`, there are routes such as `/latest`, ending up as the final route `/blog/latest`.

How would one do this properly within Angular? Or am I completely missing the point with Angular?

Comment: I'd say the best way would be to split your app into modules, then each module would have it's own routes

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do all your routing in one file, or in app.js for that matter.  It just has to be done in a config block.  Since your Angular app should be defined in the global namespace, you could have a separate file that starts like this:

```
yourAngularApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // Your routing code
]);
```

Thus you could separate your routing code however you like.

See more anout config blocks here under the headings "Module Loading & Dependencies" and "Configuration Blocks:" https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

---

> The thing I am trying to achieve is only exposing the `/blog/latest`
>   route once you request the page `/blog`, it's not relevant to know
>   `/blog/latest` exists if you're not interested in `/blog` either.

If navigating to `/blog` caused the page to refresh, this goal would not be difficult to accomplish.  You could structure your app in such a way that

- your main routes are defined in a single file, and then
- your further, `/blog`-related routes are in a separate file that *only gets downloaded when you're in that area of that application.*

However, if your application is a full-on SPA, and Angular does not get bootstrapped again when the `/blog` page is requested, this approach would not work.  There is a more-complex approach I've read about that involves saving a reference to the routeProvider for later use:

```
yourAngularApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // Your routing code
        yourAngularApp.routeProvider = $routeProvider;
]);
```

Then, you can utilize yourAngularApp.routeProvider later on (in a controller, for instance) to further configure your routing.

---

I found an even cleaner solution solution than that here:

[Deferring Route Configuration Using Decorators And Route Resolution In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2783-deferring-route-configuration-using-decorators-and-route-resolution-in-angularjs.htm)

The gist of that approach is that you can create a $route decorator during the configuration phase, and use that to expose the $routeProvider functionality.

For completeness, here are the main bits of that code.  First you define the decorator to modify $route during the configuration phase, exposing whatever functionality from $routeProvider you like (my example just shows `.when()`):

```
yourAngularApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $provide.decorator( "$route", routeDecorator );

        function routeDecorator( $delegate ) {
            var $route = $delegate;

            $route.when = function( path, route ) {
                $routeProvider.when( path, route );
                return( this );
            };

            return( $route );
        }
]);
```

Then you can inject $route into other areas, like controllers and services:

```
yourAngularApp.controller(
    "YourController",
    function($scope, $route) {
        // code that modifies routing here
        // ...
        $route.reload();
    }
);
```

Comment: The point is, that with modules such as ngRoute, it seems like everything has to be put into one file for it to work. The thing I am trying to achieve is only exposing the `/blog/latest` route once you request the page `/blog`, it's not relevant to know `/blog/latest` exists if you're not interested in `/blog` either. angular-ui-router (as mentioned by @user2892650) doesn't seem to solve this (from what I can tell)

Comment: Ah, I missed that subtly when reading your question, @RubenRutten (or at least I will call it subtle to imply that I didn't just carelessly miss your point =P).  I will update my answer to respond to your comments.

Comment: @RubenRutten Sorry for the delay, I've updated my answer (and learned something in the process!).